# is there mysql operator `both`

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am using CodeIgniter with GroceryCrud, 
when I am tring to do a search the response is mysql error.

the error contains the next message:
`Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'both last_action_date  LIKE '%11%'
both package_id  LIKE '%11%'
both at line 6`

and here is  part of the relevant query

```
...FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN `users` as j9e598a93 ON `j9e598a93`.`id` = `users`.`accountant_id`
LEFT JOIN `users` as j0b70ca4c ON `j0b70ca4c`.`id` = `users`.`affiliate_id`
WHERE  `id`  LIKE '%11%'
both `last_action_date`  LIKE '%11%'
both `package_id`  LIKE '%11%'
```

I am not familiar with the "BOTH" mysql operator and I could not find it.

does anyone knows this operator? 
is it really exists or it's a GroceryCrud bug?

Comment: I haven't heard of it in any ANSI SQL compilant RDBMS.

Comment: That looks like some odd lang/translation bug supplying `both` where `OR` is intended.

Comment: Actually guys, `both` is an MySQL reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - Yet, I for one do not know how to use it. Yet in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html it lists as `mysql> SELECT TRIM(BOTH 'x' FROM 'xxxbarxxx');`

Comment: The source of the issue in GroceryCrud is here https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/blob/master/application/models/grocery_crud_model.php#L163

Comment: @Fred-ii-
my mysql version is > 5.6 so why this count as sql error?  

can you please give me a link to this operator? I had tries to google it for long time but the word "both" is problematic for googeling :-)

Comment: [Searching the GroceryCrud codebase](https://github.com/scoumbourdis/grocery-crud/search?p=2&q=both&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for `'both'` to explain those two methods linked previously, I don't find much helpful info.  I don't know CodeIgniter well to know if this is some sort of convention the normal `like()` and `or_like()` methods don't have that parameter. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: @user2992810: it counts as an error because it's just invalid SQL syntax. There is no boolean infix operator with name `BOTH` defined in mysql.

Comment: Ok, so [CodeIgniter does use the `$side` param](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/bdb96ca1b1dbfc1791172fd169d7751cbc4d7d55/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L913),  but GroceryCrud is misusing it. You should probably open an issue on its github project.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but you could replace `BOTH` with `AND`. I say this because using `AND` or `OR` would be a valid query operator.

Answer (score 2):

> does anyone knows this operator?

In your query the `BOTH` token assumed to be used as an infix boolean operator. There is no such defined in mysql, hence mysql query parser fails to parse a query.

> is it really exists or it's a GroceryCrud bug?

It definitely is a bug caused by generating incorrect SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a  GroceryCrud bug. `BOTH` is a reserved mysql word.

Comment: "BOTH is a reserved mysql word" --- `OR` is also a reserved mysql word :-)